# How can I upload a GarageBand (.band) file into my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, audio, carrierwave

I am creating a Rails app which should allow users to upload any type of audio file format. I am currently using Carrierwave gem to accomplish this, however CarrierWave will not allow uploads of certain file formats such as .band (GarageBand default format).

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, .band is actually a folder containing multiple files. So, yes, carrierwave does not allow uploads of folders. The folder must be converted into a .zip file.